# Find coordinates for overlapping hexagonal bins between hexbin objects

Tags: r, hexagonal-tiles

I have two spatial datasets with coordinates indicating observations of a species and want to estimate the area of overlap among these datasets. Since point coordinates cannot represent an area, one has to bin the coordinates using similar x (longitude) and y (latitude) categories for both datasets.

For this task, I found the practical [hexbin](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hexbin/index.html) package, which does [hexagonal binning](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82362/what-are-the-benefits-of-hexagonal-sampling-polygons). The package is great, but at least I fail to find a function that directly outputs the coordinates / IDs of overlapping bins among `hexbin` objects. For example, the [`hdiffplot`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/hexbin/versions/1.29.0/topics/hdiffplot) returns a nice graphical **overview of overlapping bins, but how to extract this information for further analysis**?

```
library(hexbin)

set.seed(1); df1 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10, 0, 5), y = rnorm(10, 0, 5))
set.seed(2); df2 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10, 0, 5), y = rnorm(10, 0, 5))

xrange <- c(floor(min(c(df1$x, df2$x))-1), ceiling(max(c(df1$x, df2$x))+1))
#-/+1 just to make the plot nicer
yrange <- c(floor(min(c(df1$y, df2$y))-1), ceiling(max(c(df1$y, df2$y)))+1)

hb1 <- hexbin(df1$x, df1$y, xbins = 10, xbnds = xrange, ybnds = yrange)
hb2 <- hexbin(df2$x, df2$y, xbins = 10, xbnds = xrange, ybnds = yrange)

hdiffplot(hb1,hb2, xbnds = xrange, ybnds = yrange)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution to this problem while making the question. Will post it here in hopes that it will help someone one day.

You can extract the coordinates using the `hcell2xy` function. Here is a little function to find the unique and overlapping coordinates for bin centroids:

```
#' @title Print overlapping and unique bin centroid coordinates for two hexbin objects
#' @param bin1,bin2 two objects of class hexbin.
#' @details The hexbin objects for comparison, bin1 and bin2, must have the same plotting limits and cell size.
#' @return Returns a list of data frames with unique coordinates for \code{bin1} and \code{bin2} as well as overlapping coordinates among bins.

hdiffcoords <- function(bin1, bin2) {

  ## Checks modified from: https://github.com/edzer/hexbin/blob/master/R/hdiffplot.R
  if(is.null(bin1) | is.null(bin1)) {
    stop("Need 2 hex bin objects")
  } else {
        if(bin1@shape != bin2@shape)
            stop("Bin objects must have same shape parameter")
        if(all(bin1@xbnds == bin2@xbnds) & all(bin1@ybnds == bin2@ybnds))
            equal.bounds <- TRUE
        else stop("Bin objects need the same xbnds and ybnds")
        if(bin1@xbins != bin2@xbins)
            stop("Bin objects need the same number of bins")
  }

  ## Find overlapping and unique bins

  hd1 <- data.frame(hcell2xy(bin1), count_bin1 = bin1@count, cell_bin1 = bin1@cell)
  hd2 <- data.frame(hcell2xy(bin2), count_bin2 = bin2@count, cell_bin2 = bin2@cell)

  overlapping_hd1 <- apply(hd1, 1, function(r, A){ sum(A$x==r[1] & A$y==r[2]) }, hd2)
  overlapping_hd2 <- apply(hd2, 1, function(r, A){ sum(A$x==r[1] & A$y==r[2]) }, hd1)

  overlaps <- merge(hd1[as.logical(overlapping_hd1),], hd2[as.logical(overlapping_hd2),])

  unique_hd1 <- hd1[!as.logical(overlapping_hd1),]
  unique_hd2 <- hd2[!as.logical(overlapping_hd2),]

  ## Return list of data.frames

  list(unique_bin1 = unique_hd1, unique_bin2 = unique_hd2, overlapping = overlaps)

}
```

This information should be the same than returned by `hdiffplot` in graphical format:

```
df <- hdiffcoords(hb1, hb2)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = df$unique_bin1, aes(x = x, y = y), color = "red", size = 10) + 
  geom_point(data = df$unique_bin2, aes(x = x, y = y), color = "cyan", size = 10) +
  geom_point(data = df$overlapping, aes(x = x, y = y), color = "green", size = 10) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Any comments/corrections are appreciated.